# icon mismatch for button

Tags: java, android, icons

I can make icon for me or are there ready-made sites? I've tried a lot of sites, but the sizes are usually like this. How do I handle this?

I've tried a lot of icons, sizes as in the picture

[image]

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/share"
            android:background="@drawable/y"
            android:text="Değiştir"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:onClick="random"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

do button layout_height="match_parent" beacuse of wrap_content it is mismatching

Comment: my order is broken at that time. I need a site that gives 16x16 icon

Comment: http://www.simpleimageresizer.com/ here you can resize the image

Answer (score 0):

This is great source of android resources https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

Also you can try to create something like this

```
<LinearLayout...
   <ImageView...
   <TextView...
</LinearLayout>
```

And add **onClickListener** on **LinearLayout**